# How to use Tailwind CSS in React to configure Create React App?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I'm very new to use tailwindcss with react app. I've following the guide from tailwindcss but it was not well and also give lots of buggy. If anyone have idea to start up projects using tailwind and react, please share your experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's good questions. In my experience, I've started using React boilerplate project.
First, open your terminal and type the following commands to create a new project.

```
#using NPX
npx create-react-app tailwindreact-app

#using NPM
npm init react-app tailwindreact-app

#using yarn 
yarn create react-app tailwindreact-app
```

`create-react-app` is the official React build tool for scaffolding new React projects.

Go to your `app` directory

```
cd tailwindreact-app
```

Next, install Tailwind and its dependencies

```
#using npm
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9

#using Yarn
yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9 -D
```

`Create React App` does not support PostCSS 8 yet, so we need to install the version of `PostCSS7` that is compatible with `Tailwind CSS v2`

Next, we need to install `CRACO` to configure `Tailwindcss`

```
#using npm
npm install @craco/craco

#using Yarn
yarn add @craco/craco
```

First, create a CRACO configuration file in your base directory, either manually or using the following command:

```
touch craco.config.js
```

Next, add `tailwindcss` and `autoprefixer` as PostCSS plugins to your CRACO config file:

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Configure your app to use `craco` to run development and build scripts.

Open your `package.json` file and replace the content of `scripts` with:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Create the default configurations scaffold:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

This command creates a `tailwind.config.js` in your project’s base directory. The file houses all of Tailwind’s default configuration. We can also add an optional --full flag to generate a configuration file with all the defaults Tailwind comes with.

**Including Tailwind in your CSS**

Inside your `src` folder create a folder named `styles`. This is where all your styles will be stored.

Inside that folder, create a `tailwind.css` and an `index.css` file.

The `index.css` file is where we’ll import tailwind’s base styles and configurations. `tailwind.css` will contain the compiled output of the `index.css`.

**Tailwind CSS components, utilities, and base styles**

Add the following to your `index.css` file.

```
//index.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

``@tailwind is a tailwind directive that is used to inject default `base styles`, `components`, `utilities` and custom configurations.

@tailwind base **injects Tailwind’s base styles, which is a combination of Normalize.css and some additional base styles.

`@tailwind components` injects any component (small reusable styles such as buttons, form elements, etc.) classes registered by plugins defined in your tailwind config file.

Below the component import is where you would add any of your custom component classes — things that you’d want to be loaded before the default utilities so the utilities could still override them.

Here’s an example:

```
.btn { ... }
.form-input { ... }
```

`@tailwind utilities` injects all of Tailwind’s utility classes (including the default and your utilities), which are generated based on your config file.

Below the utilities import is where you would add any custom utilities you need that don’t come out of the box with Tailwind.

Example:

```
.bg-pattern-graph-paper { ... }
.skew-45 { ... }
```

Tailwind swaps all these directives out at build time and replaces them with the CSS generated.

**Configure your app to build your CSS file**
To configure your app to use `CRACO` to build your styles every time you run the `npm start` or `yarn start` command, open your `package.json` file and replace the content of `scripts` with:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build:style": "tailwind build src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

To import your CSS to the app, open your `index.js` file and import your Tailwind styles:

```
import './styles/tailwind.css';
```

Delete the `index.css` and `app.css` files in your projects root directory and remove their corresponding import statements in the `Index.js` and `App.js` files, respectively.

Your `index.js` file should look similar to this:

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/tailwind.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
```

That's all.
I hope my experience will help others.

Comment: I'm not test it but your answer is very detail. thanks! :)

Comment: Ok. I will try to help others in my aspect of development.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed the official docs for tailwind which can be found [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

Comment: When i've configure the tailwind css, it occured npm install error and can't inject tailwind in react boilerplate.

Comment: If you could post the error... It would easy to solve the error